# turn joined rows into column in sql

Tags: sql

please help i want to change the following table

```
StudentCode CourseCode  Year    term    ExamModel   score   School
102188452   1522            80  1      1            6.25    46622401
102188452   1522            80  1      2            10  46622401
102188452   1522            80  1      3             7  46622401
102188452   1522            80  1      4             5  46622401
102188452   1522            80  2      1             10 46622401
102188452   1525            80  1      1             6.5    46622401
102188452   1525            80  1      2             12 46622401
102188452   1525            80  1      3            13.75   46622401
102188452   1525            80  1      4             14 46622401
102188452   1525            80  2      1             10 46622401
102188452   5435            80  1      1             11 46622401
102188452   5435            80  1      2              8 46622401
102188452   5435            80  1      3             10 46622401
102188452   5435            80  1      4             13 46622401
102188452   7991            78  1      1             15 46620903
102188452   7991            78  1      3             19 46620903
102188452   7991            79  1      1             10 46622304
102188452   7991            79  1      3             17 46622304
102188452   7991            80  1      1             18 46622401
102188452   7991            80  1      3             17 46622401
```

I want the following table

```
Student        Course   Year   term    model1  model2 model3  model4     school
102188452           1522    80  1   6.25    10  7   5   46622401
102188452           1525    80  1   6.5 12  13.75   14  46622401
102188452           5435    80  1   11  8   10  13  46622401
102188452           7991    80  1   18  ….. 17  ……  46622401
102188452           1522    80  2   10  ….. ….. ….. 46622401
102188452           1525    80  2   10  ….. ….. ….. 46622401
102188452           7991    78  1   15  ….. 19  ….. 46620903
102188452           7991    79  1   10  ….. ….. ….. 46622304
102188452           7991    79  1   ….. ….. 17  ….. 46622304
```

Comment: How `model1  model2 model3  model4` should be evaluated?

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
SELECT StudentCode, CourseCode,  Year, term,  
SUM(case when ExamModel = 1 then score else 0 end) 'model1',
SUM(case when ExamModel = 2 then score else 0 end) 'model2',
SUM(case when ExamModel = 3 then score else 0 end) 'model3',
SUM(case when ExamModel = 4 then score else 0 end) 'model4',
,School
FROM your_table
GROUP BY StudentCode, CourseCode,  Year, term, School
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE` to map rows to columns and then
use `GROUP BY` to show all 4 mapped columns by in 1 row:

```
SELECT StudentCode, CourseCode,  Year, term,  
    MAX(CASE WHEN ExamModel = 1 THEN score END) AS 'model1',
    MAX(CASE WHEN ExamModel = 2 THEN score END) AS 'model2',
    MAX(CASE WHEN ExamModel = 3 THEN score END) AS 'model3',
    MAX(CASE WHEN ExamModel = 4 THEN score END) AS 'model4',
    School
FROM T
GROUP BY StudentCode, CourseCode,  Year, term, School
```

[see example in SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72397/2/0)